# Best Method to Track User Location Inside a Building

Tags: android, iphone, networking, mobile, wifi

What is the most accurate way to track a user inside a building - where GPS is not present?

Can you use WiFi to track users in a given space?

User would be using a smartphone (Droid, iPhone) with an application to communicate with the server/routers/location system in the building. The system would show the users in the building on a custom-map and their location.

Comment: first of all make a study yourself! if you not found what you need,then ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your best trick and probably not very accurate, would be to use multiple wifi/bluetooth sources and then use signal strength proportions to designate location. The more sources you have the more accurate you could make it.

check

- [How to obtain the current location inside a building using an iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318437/how-to-obtain-the-current-location-inside-a-building-using-an-iphone)
- [Locate an iPhone reliably indoors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056207/locate-an-iphone-reliably-indoors?rq=1)
- [how to get current location inside a building iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915306/how-to-get-current-location-inside-a-building-iphone?rq=1)

Comment: Are there any routers that can be used to determine location of a device using 802.11 or other wireless protocols to help with location?

Assuming no Bluetooth. What's the smartest way to track an iPhone user's locations indoors?

Comment: if device have internet it'll map your location even the GPS is turned off.The 'CLLoactionManager' will try to triangulate the location by wifi first, then cell towers and will use GPS as the last option.

Comment: Everything with ios location service :http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4995?viewlocale=en_US